# I just got two hats, why?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I just received two Hats, but I'm not sure what I did to get them.
Not that I don't want them, just curious. Especially since I got them on a site I'm not too active on.

*Following are the Hats*:

- Just Here for the Hat
- Where in the World

I've just seen there is a description under each hat, from which I understand how I got the "Just here for the Hat" hat, but "*this is a secret hat*" doesn't quite explain the "Where in the World" hat.

Comment: Posting this question inadvertently lead to me becoming Darth Vader. Worth any down-votes it might get ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find a description of all the standard and secret hats on meta.SE:

**[Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271)**

The secret hats have spoilers that reveal how they are awarded when you mouse over the yellow areas. The post is updated as people discover the details over time. Where in the World is a known one. I won't repeat the spoiler here.